# Robot Framework in Mainframe Testing

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, mainframe

I am trying to write a simple .robot Script on Mainframe testing. Using below library to connect to wc3270.exe terminal.

https://github.com/pedrommvv/x3270-robot

Here's my sample .robot script.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Automation3270.py

*** Variables ***
${hostname}       XXXX

*** Test Cases ***
Should be able to Open Terminal
    Open MainConnection
    Enter Logon

*** Keywords ***
Open MainConnection
    Open 3270    |${hostname}

Enter Logon
    Input Text On Field    24  1  'logon'
```

"Open MainConnection" step getting executed successfully though,facing below error when I try to send input string to wc3270.exe using x and y coordinates.

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is
>   not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto
>   call) no address was supplied.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I setup an environment similar to what you've described but not being a robot expert I need your help.  Do you have a corresponding resource file that I'm missing?  I'm getting the following message when trying to execute your script:  Should be able to Open Terminal                                       | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Open 3270' found.

I have an inkling of your problem which I think is a host issue but would like to recreate to be sure.

Comment: I have updated the code. PFB. Need to import the Automation3270.py which i had downloaded from the specified github link.

Answer (score -1):

try use the library Mainframe3270 https://github.com/Altran-PT-GDC/Robot-Framework-Mainframe-3270-Library

This should work:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Mainframe3270.py

*** Variables ***
${hostname}       XXXX

*** Test Cases ***
Should be able to Open Terminal
    Open MainConnection
    Enter Logon

*** Keywords ***
Open MainConnection
    Open Connection    ${hostname}

Enter Logon
    Wait Field Detected
    Write Bare In Position    1    24    logon
```

Comment: Also, make sure that you disclose your affiliation with the linked library. Failure to say that you're one of the developers of a software you recommend can be interpreted as **spam**. Read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) on how to go about linking your product.